# Mbtiles to underlying dataset

Tags: mapbox, geojson, mapbox-gl-js, mbtiles, maptiler

I have a `.mbtiles` and would like to convert it back to a dataset so I can edit it.
I don't see a convert/export button for this function on mapbox studio or maptiler.
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a tool like https://github.com/mapbox/mbtiles-extracts .

In general it's a problematic, lossy process, and you're better off trying to get the original source data from somewhere else.